# Find the number of digits of the number $k$ in function of $r$ and $n$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $α∈(0,1)$ be an irrational number with infinitely digits after the decimal point. Let $r>4$ and $n>1$ be positive integers. Let $$k=⌊r^{n²}α⌋$$

where $⌊.⌋$ is the floor function.

My **question** is: Find the number of digits of the number $k$ in function of $r$ and $n$.

Comment: Do you know how to express the number of digits of $k$ in terms of $\log_{10}k$?

Comment: "Infinitely many digits after the coma": 1. every irrational number has infinitely many digits after the "coma". 2. It's called "decimal point", not "comma" (and most certainly not "coma").

Comment: @RossMillikan: No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of digits of $k$ is $\lfloor \log_{10} k \rfloor +1$.  For example, $\log_{10} 1234=3+$ and $1234$ has $4$ digits.  So (leaving aside the floor for now) $\log_{10} k= \log_{10}(r^{n^2}\alpha)=n^2\log_{10}r+\log_{10}\alpha$  $$1+\lfloor \log_{10} k\rfloor= 1+\lfloor n^2\log_{10}r+\log_{10}\alpha\rfloor$$

Answer (score 2):

Looks like $\lceil\log_{10}(r^{n^2}\alpha)\rceil=\lceil n^2\log_{10}r+\log_{10}\alpha\rceil$ to me.

Comment: This function also includes $\alpha$.

Comment: @barakmanos:  it has to.

Comment: The question doesn't say so... and I think that taking $\log_{10}$ in order to count the number of decimal digits works pretty much for every number, doesn't it?

Comment: @barakmanos:  yes, $\log_{10}$ works for all numbers, but OP says he doesn't know that.

Comment: OK, but it seems to me like a "general answer", rather than an answer which takes into "special consideration" the specific details within the question (such as $0<\alpha<1,r>4,n>1$). Also, as I've already mentioned, it makes use of $\alpha$, which is "outside" the given restrictions of the question at hand. If it is indeed impossible without the value of $\alpha$ as you say, then the question is ill-formed. If you can prove it by showing two different values of $\alpha$ which yield two different results for the same values of $r$ and $n$, then I guess it "wraps it up".

Comment: @barakmanos With $r=5$ and $n=2$, we have $3$ for $\alpha=1/\pi$ and $2$ for $\alpha=1/\pi^2$. There's no way how to express the answer independently of $\alpha$; we can make $r^{n^2}$ as huge as we want while making it as small as we want with some $\alpha$. The only meaningful answer independent of $\alpha$ is an *upper bound* on the number of digits in $k$.